# pyserial/python and real time data acquisition

Tags: python, real-time, pyserial

I have an infrared camera/tracker with which I am communicating via the serial port. I'm using the pyserial module to do this at the moment. The camera updates the position of a tracked object at the rate of 60 Hz. In order to get the position of the tracked object I execute one pyserial.write() and then listen for an incoming reply with pyserial.read(serialObj.inWaiting()). Once the reply/position has been received the while loop is reentered and so on. My question has to do with the reliability and speed of this approach. I need the position to be gotten by the computer at the rate of at least 60Hz (and the position will then be sent via UDP to a real-time OS). Is this something that Pyserial/Python are capable of or should I look into alternative C-based approaches?

Thanks,
Luke

Comment: How did this turn out? What sort of sampling rates were you able to get with python? I've done some simple data acquisition off of an ohaus scale over RS232, but was only able to get 5hz (might have been the scale)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python *should* keep up fine, but the best thing to do is make sure you monitor how many reads per second you are getting. Count how many times the read completed each second, and if this number is too low, write to a performance log or similar. You should also consider decoupling the I/O part from the rest of your python program (if there is one) as pyserial read calls are blocking.

Comment: thanks for all the answers everyone. i guess i'll test the performance of the read/write pyserial functions before i consider moving onto something else. but could you explain the blocked serial calls and why they perhaps require decoupling the rest of the program (you're right, the reading/writing is only a small part of the required functionality).

Comment: Pyserial will by default block on read calls (you can configure it so it doesn't do this). What this means is that when you call `read`, the whole program sits and waits for something to be written, then reads it, then your program can continue. There are a couple of ways around this, by either using non-blocking calls (`read` returns immediately, but maybe with nothing), event driven frameworks like twisted (twisted knows you're waiting and does other things in the meantime), or by using processes/threading (though you have the same problem listening for incoming messages from the process).

Comment: yeah, i've set the timeout=0 and then end up getting one char at a time. that is, i perform serial.read(1) within a while loop and check for '\r' which indicates the end of the return command and when that condition is met i then issue a new get position request. from some brief experimentation, it doesn't seem like i've missed any frames in the camera system, which is great, although i'd like to somehow ensure that this is always the case. like if i open a browser while the program is executing, is there a way to force the script to have highest priority?

Comment: That'll work, but it's not very efficient - you could be reading it thousands of times a second, and as you're only getting one char at a time you might not be keeping up with the arriving data. I would use twisted and schedule a loopingcall to read *all* waiting data from the pipe 60 times per second. This should significantly reduce your overhead.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a matter of latency than speed.

Python always performs memory allocation and release, but if the data is reused, the same memory will be reused by the C library.
So the OS (C library / UDP/IP stack) will have more impact than Python itself.

I really think you should use a serial port on your RTOS machine and use C code and pre-allocated buffers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that Python will keep up with the data just fine. My advice would be to try it, and if Python appears to lag, then try PyPy instead — an implementation of Python that compiles most of your inner loops down to machine code for speed close so that of C.

http://pypy.org/